# How to test a gRPC interceptor in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, grpc, interceptor

I have an .net core application where we're implementing both a REST and gRPC api.
We're using the middleware for authentication and authorization with JWT tokens and it's workning just fine!
I have made an Interceptor that will intercept all calls to UnaryServerHandler and that is also working as expected. I'm using the interceptor to authorize provided incoming gRPC headers. A client can be authenticated with an ApiKey (guid) and then provide customer api keys with each call, and these customer keys should be validated on each request.

My problem is that when I try to unit test the Interceptor; the `UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation` will contain different data that I cannot figure out how to mock properly.

The interceptor performs some reflection code to figure out which gRPC service the requested method if found in and will validate an attribute on that method.`

This is my interceptor class.

```
{

    internal class AuthorizeApplicationKeyInterceptor : Interceptor
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Will find and return all AuthorizeApplicationKeyAttribute that are set on the method.
        /// If more than one attribute is set, that means that the application must have att least one role for each attribute.
        /// Else the application only needs to have one of the roles in the attribute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="serviceType">The service where we will get the method from</param>
        /// <param name="methodName">The method where we will find the attributes.</param>
        /// <param name="inputParameterTypes"></param>
        /// <returns>If no attributes exist on the method; null is returned, else all attributes.</returns>
        private AuthorizeApplicationKeyAttribute[] GetAuthorizeApplicationKeyAttributeForMethod(Type serviceType, string methodName, Type[] inputParameterTypes)
        {
            MethodInfo methodInfo = serviceType.GetMethod(methodName, inputParameterTypes);

            var attributes = methodInfo?.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuthorizeApplicationKeyAttribute), true);
            if (attributes == null || attributes.Length == 0)
                return null;

            return attributes as AuthorizeApplicationKeyAttribute[];
        }

      
        public override async Task<TResponse> UnaryServerHandler<TRequest, TResponse>(
            TRequest request,
            ServerCallContext context,
            UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
        {
            var targetType = continuation.Target.GetType();

            // Get the service type for the service we're calling a method in.
            var serviceType = targetType.GenericTypeArguments[0];

            // Get the method name by splitting the context.Method and get the last part that should be the method name.
            var method = context.Method;
            var methodSplit = method.Split('/');
            var requestedMethodName = methodSplit.Last();

            // Get the input type for the method so we find the correct method even if we've two methods that are called the same but have different input parameters.
            Type[] types = new List<Type>() { targetType.GenericTypeArguments[1], typeof(ServerCallContext) }.ToArray();

            // Get the attributes for the method. If null is returned then no attributes were found.
            var attributes = GetAuthorizeApplicationKeyAttributeForMethod(serviceType, requestedMethodName, types);
            if (attributes != null)
            {
                var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
                var applicationKey = context.ApplicationKey();
                // Validate that the application key has the expected roles.
                // If we have multiple attributes then the application must have at least one of the roles for every attribute.
                foreach (AuthorizeApplicationKeyAttribute attribute in attributes)
                {
                    await attribute.ValidateApplicationKey(httpContext, applicationKey);
                }
            }

            return await continuation(request, context);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to mock the continuation parameter with no luck.
I've also tried to create a new grpc server in the unit test file and call a method, but the continuation property will still not contain the same "necessary" properties as when I call the api from a client.

The continuation method seems to be of the type `ResolvedInterceptorInvoker` when called from a client and when called from a unit test it will just be the invoked method.

Should I approach this in some other way?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I've decided that the solution wasn't to use an Interceptor, so I created some middleware to do kind of the same thing without the fuss of the Interceptor not being testable.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check the request.  The request from the client and your test method should look exactly the same.  You have to help us and let us know exactly what differences exist in the request.

Comment: @jdweng I've tried Wireshark but as I'm not familiar with the program and gRPC communication is done with binary data, I couldn't really parse anything useful from it. Fiddler, from what I understand, doesn't support gRPC(http2) yet. I think this has to do with the middleware added to the .net core application when adding gRPC. We're using the NuGet package Grpc.AspNetCore 2.31.0.

Comment: It looks like it is using TLS with encryption so all the data is in the TCP packets.  HTTPS (secure) is the application layer and uses TCP for the transport layer.  Or it is using GZIP.  You should see in Wireshark the TLS version and then multiple TCP packets (each has max size of 1500 bytes).  If you are not seeing TLS then it is not encrypted and Wireshark should show useful info.

Comment: Thank you, but I have downloaded a fork of the Grpc.AspNetCore project, and by following the code I have concluded that the code will perform some mutations of the request before if reaches the interceptor class. The classes that are used are internal classes so I cannot use them to mock or fake the parameters to the interceptor.